# Replace input text fields in html with data inside

Tags: javascript, html, regex

'tab_text' is a html code regenerated from 'mytable' by this code. All i want is for this regenerated html to have input values instead of input text fields. It will be used for some extraction task. For this , i found some code snippet and tried to edit that for my benefit:

```
var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
var j=0;
mytable = document.getElementById('countersTable'); // id of table

    for(j = 0 ; j < mytable.rows.length ; j++)
    {
        tab_text=tab_text+mytable.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";

    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "")
```

Obviously, I need to add a regex instead of `""` at last line. I tried `input[type=text][id^=*]` It did not work.

Would you please help me find a solution to that issue?

Comment: `input[type=text][id^=*]` isn't a RegEx it's a jQuery selctor

Comment: @Liam or CSS selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions here, it's much simpler to use DOM methods. In your case [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) will work well.

First of all, you need to select all input, fields. Then you iterate over the collection, and finally replace every with its value.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var text = document.createTextNode(inputs[i].value);
    inputs[i].parentNode.replaceChild(text, inputs[i]);
}
```

```html
<div>
    Some <input type="text" value="Thomas" />
</div>
<p>One more <input type="text" value="Field" /></p>
```

In the demo above, all the `input` fields will be replaced. Of course, you can extend CSS selector in querySelectorAll to process other form elements if you need: `input, textarea, select`.

**UPD**. This is how you can combine above solution with your code to get text representation of the table with inputs turned into text:

```
var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
var j = 0;
var mytable = document.getElementById('countersTable'); // id of table

for (j = 0; j < mytable.rows.length; j++) {

    var rowClone = mytable.rows[j].cloneNode(true),
        inputs = rowClone.querySelectorAll('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var text = document.createTextNode(inputs[i].value);
        inputs[i].parentNode.replaceChild(text, inputs[i]);
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + rowClone.innerHTML + "</tr>";
}

tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hn7Lakx6/

Comment: it must be done only inside 'mytable'. I mean, only inputs inside 'tab_text' must be converted to their values. How can i succeed that?

Comment: `tab_text` is id or class?

Comment: it is a html code regenerated from 'mytable' by this code. All i want is for this regenerated html to have input values instead of input text fields

Comment: Check this demo of how you can combine my solution with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/hn7Lakx6/